# Conflict between Log4Net's ThreadContext and Task

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task, log4net

Has anyone tried to stack contexts and use Tasks at the same time?

I'm trying something like this:

```
using (log4net.ThreadContext.Stacks["contextLog"].Push("Saving Data"))
{
    log.Info("Starting transaction");
    var taskList = new List<Task>();
    taskList.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        log.Info("Inside Transaction");
    }));
    Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
}
```

and I'm getting that result:

```
2015/42/26 13:42:10,841 INFO  [Saving Data] Starting transaction
2015/42/26 13:42:10,870 INFO  [(null)] Inside Transaction
```

I was expecting it to have **[Saving Data]** instead of **[(null)]**  on the second line.

It appears to lose access to the log4net ThreadContext Stack as soon as it starts a new Task.

Do you know how to avoid this?

EDIT: At first o thought is was a problem with Transaction Scope, but as @stuartd pointed me, it was working fine. Then I realized that there was a task and that was the real problem.

Comment: Can't reproduce this - https://gist.github.com/stuartd/81c8754391aa1a580da0 - can you update this with more code so it is reproducible?

Comment: @stuartd you're right. I've changed the question to reflect the real problema: System.Threading.Tasks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The task will run on a different thread so the data in the `ThreadContext` stack isn't available, you should use the `log4net.LogicalThreadContext` instead as data in that should follow the logical execution and still be visible to the `Task`