# log4net context setting. how to propogate context to child threads spawn by Task parallel library

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

I am using following code for setting log4net context

```
 public static IDisposable ThreadContextSet(string key, object value)
        {
            //object oldVal = ThreadContext.Properties[key];
            ThreadContext.Properties[key] = value;
            var topMostCleaner = new DispCleaner();
            topMostCleaner.EvDispose += () => {
                // Pop = restore old value
                //ThreadContext.Properties[key] = oldVal;
                ThreadContext.Properties[key] = null;
            };
            return topMostCleaner;
        }

        private class DispCleaner : IDisposable
        {
            public event Action EvDispose;

            public void Dispose()
            {
                if (EvDispose != null)
                {
                    EvDispose();
                }
            }
        }
```

Problem is when i am creating child Thread from method the context is not transferring to those thread.

Like

```
public void InitiateTransaction(InitiateTransactionRequest info)
{
..
...
                using (Log4NetExt.ThreadContextSet(StringConstants.Log4NetContextConstants.Ip, this.RequestIp))
                using (Log4NetExt.ThreadContextSet(StringConstants.Log4NetContextConstants.TransactionMsisdn, msisdn))
                using (Log4NetExt.ThreadContextSet(StringConstants.Log4NetContextConstants.TransactionId, transactionId))
                {

                ...
                ....

                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessTransactionAync()); // context not transfer
                }

}
```

Can any body help me in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have changed code from ThreadContext.Properties to LogicalThreadContext.Properties
And looks like it is working

Reference link for solution is [Conflict between Log4Net's ThreadContext and Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32233419/conflict-between-log4nets-threadcontext-and-task)